# SQLite and reading database from runnable .jar

Tags: java, sqlite, executable-jar

I was struggling a lot last few hours to make my swing project making use of sqlite database to work from runnable jar. What I came up with was that I had to make jar, then copy existing .db files to the same location and then hit the wall.

One of my db files contains logins and passwords and I couldn't get logged in for no obvious reason.

This problem existed while double clicking, or right-clicking to execute.

When I started my jar from command line I was finally able to use logins & passwords from my database and correctly read all the data from my database.

Still, need an explenation why command line works and others don't. Also, how to solve my problem and make it runnable on click?

Any help will be greatly appreciated and thanks for your time.

Comment: How do you run it with command line?

Comment: @pingw33n java -jar myname.jar